# Error HH604 Windows: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: node.js, solidity, hardhat

I get this error: Error HH604: Error running JSON-RPC server: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

When I run: npx hardhat node

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please share the content of your hardhat config file? *Attention: please censor any API/account keys if you pasted them directly*

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this before your command

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Comment: Could you explain what this command does to future readers?

Comment: Sure, the error comes up becase the lastest Node update includes now OpenSSL 3.0 (instead of OpenSSL 1.1.1). This 3.0 has new limits on algorithms and key sizes. This command basically overrides this, using the good old 1.1.1